# Restrict attribute usage to be mutually exclusive at design time?

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm developing a serialization class that uses attributes on custom classes to decorate whether a property is a fixed length format or a delimited format.  These two attributes should be mutually exclusive, meaning that the developer can either specify `[FixedLength]` or `[Delimited]` (with appropriate constructors) on a property, but not both.  In order to reduce complexity and increase cleanliness, I *don't* want to combine the attributes and set a flag based on the format type, e.g. `[Formatted(Formatter=Formatting.Delimited)]`.  Is it possible to restrict these attributes to be mutually exclusive to one another at design time?  I'm aware how I can check for this scenerio at run-time.

Comment: +1: I would be interesting in that answer too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this in .NET. At most you can allow a single instance of the *same* attribute on a class, like in this example:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class BaseAttribute : Attribute {
}

[Base]
[Base] // compiler error here
class DoubleBase { 
}
```

But this behavior cannot be extended to derived classes, i.e. if you do this it compiles:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class BaseAttribute : Attribute {
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class Derived1Attribute : BaseAttribute {
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class Derived2Attribute : BaseAttribute {
}

[Derived1]
[Derived2] // this one is ok
class DoubleDerived {
}
```

The best I can think of is that you could write something to check that there are no types with both attributes applied and use the check as a post-build step.

Comment: @George: it's quite a long time I don't use it, but the FileHelpers library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/filehelpers/) probably does something very similar to what you are trying to do... you could have a look at how they solved the problem...